# Comments vs. Pingbacks next page issue

Tags: comments, pingbacks

I have a really annoying problem.

If there are no comments, comments won't show up.
If there are no pingbacks, won't show up.

However, if there are pingbacks and I have a lot of comments, so there's a page 2, page 3 etc. of comments, then the following happens:
The pingbacks show up properly on [page 1](http://www.zoomingjapan.com/2011/image-test-hover/#comments).
If I go to [page 2](http://www.zoomingjapan.com/2011/image-test-hover/comment-page-2/#comments), I see the HTML markup for the Pingbacks, but no actual pingbacks.

I don't understand why.
What I want is that either the same pingbacks as on page 1 show up or no HTML markup (and no pings) at all.

You can see the problem here.
On page one everything works fine, but on page 2 I only get the HTML markup for the pingbacks.

Here's the code:

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <?php if ( ! empty($comments_by_type['comment']) ) : ?>
       <h2 class="h2comments"><img src="http://zoomingjapan.com/wp-content/themes/alltuts-child/images/comments_big.png" /><?php comments_number('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments' );?> <a href="#respond" class="addComment"><img src="http://zoomingjapan.com/wp-content/themes/alltuts/images/add_your_coment_ver2.png" border="0"></a></h2>


        <ul class="commentlist">
      <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=mytheme_comment'); ?>
<div class="navigation">
  <?php paginate_comments_links(); ?> 
 </div>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>



        <?php if ( ! empty($comments_by_type['pings']) ) : ?>
        <h2 id="pings">Trackbacks/Pingbacks</h2>
    <ul class="pinglist">
    <?php wp_list_comments('type=pings&callback=list_pings'); ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>



 <?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

        <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
                <!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

        <?php else : // comments are closed ?>
                <!-- If comments are closed. -->
                <p class="nocomments">Comments are closed.</p>

        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What I already tried was to reposition or even remove the navigation. It didn't change a thing.

Any other ideas?

**EDIT: October 21st**

If it doesn't work to remove the HTML markup, then how about displaying a message within the HTML markup instead, something like "Sorry, but there are no pings yet."
I tried this, but nothing is being displayed:

```
  <?php if ( ! empty($comments_by_type['pings']) ) : ?>
    <h2 id="pings">Trackbacks/Pingbacks</h2>
    <ul class="pinglist">
    <?php wp_list_comments('type=pings&callback=list_pings'); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php 
         else :
         echo '<p class="no-pingbacks">sorry but there are no pingbacks yet</p>';
        endif; 
         ?>
```

I hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're listing pings separately from comments, you probably need to filter `get_comments_number` to exclude pings. [Here's how I do it](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology/blob/master/functions/wordpress-hooks.php#L135):

```
<?php
function oenology_comment_count( $count ) {  
// Only filter the comments number
// in the front-end display
if ( 
// WordPress conditional that returns true if
// the current page is in the WP-Admin back-end
! is_admin() 
) {
    global $id;
    $comments_by_type = &separate_comments( get_comments( 'status=approve&post_id=' . $id ) );
    return count( $comments_by_type['comment'] );
} 
// Otherwise, when in the WP-Admin
// back end, don't filter comments
// number
else {
    return $count;
}
}
// Hook custom comment number into 'get_comments_number'
add_filter('get_comments_number', 'oenology_comment_count', 0);
?>
```

I am fairly certain this will also impact the comments count with respect to comment pagination, as well. (Caveat: your pings list will output *unpaginated*.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I've put the code into my function.php. Where in my code above should I call the function in order to make it work properly?

Comment: This is a filter; you don't need to add any code to your template files.

Comment: Oh, I'm asking because after I've added the code, I still have the exact same problem as before, so it didn't work, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hello again :) As this didn't work out, do you have any other ideas how to solve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please see my updated question :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Looks like I solved it. In case anyone else is facing this issue:

Replace this :

```
wp_list_comments('type=pings&callback=list_pings');
```

By this:

```
wp_list_comments('type=pings&callback=list_pings&page=1&per_page=1000');
```